# filtering an array issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm importing an array into a module, and adding and removing items from that array. when I give a push, it adds the item to the array globally, so much so that if I use that same array in another module, it will include this item that I pushed. but when I try to filter, with that same array getting itself with the filter, it only removes in that specific module. How can I make it modify globally?

```
let { ignore } = require('../utils/handleIgnore');
const questions = require('./quesiton');

const AgendarCollector = async (client, message) => {
    ignore.push(message.from);
    let counter = 0;
    const filter = (m) => m.from === message.from;
    const collector = client.createMessageCollector(message.from, filter, {
        max: 4,
        time: 1000 * 60,
    });
    await client.sendText(message.from, questions[counter++]);

    collector.on('start', () => {});
    await collector.on('collect', async (m) => {
        if (m) {
            if (counter < questions.length) {
                await client.sendText(message.from, questions[counter++]);
            }
        }
    });
    await collector.on('end', async (all) => {
        ignore = ignore.filter((ignored) => ignored !== message.from);
        console.log(ignore);
        const finished = [];
        if (all.size < questions) {
            console.log('não terminado');
        }
        await all.forEach((one) => finished.push(` ${one.content}`));
        await client.sendText(message.from, `${finished}.\nConfirma?`);
    });
};

module.exports = AgendarCollector;
```

see, in this code, import the ignore array and i push an item to then when the code starts and remove when its end.
but the item continues when I check that same array in another module.
I tried to  change this array ignore by using functions inside this module but still not working

```
let ignore = [];

const addIgnore = (message) => {
    ignore.push(message.from);
};
const removeIgnore = (message) => {
    ignore = ignore.filter((ignored) => ignored !== message.from);
    console.log(ignore);
};
console.log(ignore);
module.exports = { ignore, addIgnore, removeIgnore };
```

Comment: Have you tried using getters ?

Comment: can you send me an exemple of the usage?

Comment: I have provided example with code in my answer get a look at it. Reach out in comments if you need any further details or explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variables for import and export and hence cought up with issues.

Instead, make use of getters.

Write a function which will return the array of `ignore`. something like this:

```
const getIgnoredList = () => {
    return ignore;
};
```

and in your first code, import `getIgnoredList` and replace `ignore` with `getIgnoredList()`

Explanation :

Whenever we import the **variables** only the **value at that particular time** will be imported and there will not be any data binding. Hence there won't be any change in the data even though you think you are updating the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use require(...) statement it's executed only once. Hence when you try to access the property it gives the same value everytime.
Instead you should use getters

```
let data = {
   ignore : [],
   get getIgnore() {
     return this.ignore
   }
}
module.export = {
  getIgnore: data.getIgnore,
}
```

Then wherever you want to access `ignore` do

`var {getIgnore}= require('FILE_NAME')`

Now: `console.log(getIgnore)` will invoke the getter and give you current value of `ignore`

Using getters will allow you to access particular variables from other modules but if you want to make changes in value of those variables from other module you have to use setter.

More about getters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

More about setters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)